# Get CASE NUMBER printed for WHEN ORDER BY Clause in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, case, sql-order-by

Is there a way to know (or at least print) which WHEN CASE got executed for which result from MYSQL query?

for e.g., I have the following SQL which gives a priority order for the ORDER by clause.

```
select col1,col2 from tablename
WHERE col1 like '%var1%' and col2<>'0'
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN col1 = 'somevalue' THEN 0
    WHEN col1 LIKE '%,somevalue,%' THEN 1
    WHEN col2 LIKE '%,somevalue,%' THEN 2
    WHEN col2 LIKE '%somevalue%' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
  END
limit 500
```

The result comes up, but for each row returned as result, I want to also print the CASE NUMBER (0,1,2,3,4) which got matched.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT col1, col2,
       CASE
         WHEN col1 = 'somevalue' THEN 0
         WHEN col1 LIKE '%,somevalue,%' THEN 1
         WHEN col2 LIKE '%,somevalue,%' THEN 2
         WHEN col2 LIKE '%somevalue%' THEN 3
         ELSE 4
       END AS result
FROM tablename
WHERE col1 like '%var1%' and col2<>'0'
ORDER BY result
LIMIT 500;
```